# VSCode syntax highlighting changes in the middle of words since update

Tags: visual-studio-code

This morning, I updated VS Code to `1.72.0`, and since updating, I've noticed that the syntax highlighting has gone haywire.

Here's an example in Typescript language mode where it is highlighting in the middle of words:

[image: VSCode changing syntax highlighting in the middle of words]

I have tried reloading the window several times, but the issue persists. Any ideas on how to fix?

Comment: what does the TextMate scope say about the 2 parts of the string

Comment: Fortunately, this issue ended up resolving itself, but frustratingly for those who might encounter something similar, I was not able to diagnose the issue or figure out what I had done to resolve it.

Comment: they have released v1.72.1, maybe it is fixed there

Comment: For me, the issue resolved itself prior to installing `1.72.1`.